# More advanced examples with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am learning Hadoop and Apache Crunch and most of the examples I could find are word count!

Looking for something more complicated, How do we write to a local database?  Let's say I have  one of those word count examples but instead of writing it to another file I want to learn how to write it to a db, for example a MySQL DB.

Have you seen any example like that anywhere that I can take a look?

Comment: Writing to a database needn't be any different to normal, I've used JDBC from within map reduce jobs, you just need to make sure you're careful with cleanup and resource handling. As for other more advanced examples, just try out whatever comes to mind if it fits with MR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit http://university.cloudera.com/ , they have good learning materials with variety of examples.

One guy having similar problem as yours had started a project [here](http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-map-reduce-examples/).
You may look for the [Anagram example](http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-map-reduce-examples/wiki/Anagram_Example) and the [Geo Location example](http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-map-reduce-examples/wiki/Wikipedia_GeoLocation) there.(I do not know in what detail they have the examples.)

And as for database access from hadoop, read [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/).

Also if you can then go ahead and purchase this book : [Manning: Hadoop in Action](http://www.manning.com/lam/). It does have some complex examples too.

Answer (score 0):

You may take look at this link as well 
The first example talks about how to write a map reduce program to do analytics for online music website.
http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/mapreduce/advanced-map-reduce-examples-1.html
The second example talks about how to do Call Data Record Analytics using Map Reduce Program.
http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/mapreduce/advanced-map-reduce-examples-2.html

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.